# A bash script to run a program for directories that do not have a certain file

Tags: linux, shell, exec

I need  a Bash Script to Execute a program  for all directories that do not have a specific file and create the output file on the same directory.This program needs an input file which exist in every directory with the name ***.DNA.fasta**.Suppose I have the following directories that may contain sub directories also

```
dir1/a.protein.fasta  
dir2/b.protein.fasta  
dir3/anyfile  
dir4/x.orf.fasta
```

I have started by finding the directories that don't have that specific file whic name is  ***.protein.fasta**
in this case I want the `dir3` and `dir4` to be listed  (since they do not  contain `*.protein.fasta`)
I have tried this code:

```
find . -maxdepth 1  -type d  \! -exec test -e '{}/*protein.fasta' \; -print
```

but it seems I missed some thing it does not work.
also I do not know how to proceed for the whole story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one.

I can't think of a *good* solution.  But here's a solution, nevertheless.  Note that this is *guaranteed not* to work if your directory or file names contain newlines, and it's *not guaranteed* to work if they contain other special characters.  (I've only tested with the samples in your question.)

Also, I haven't included a `-maxdepth` because you said you need to search subdirectories too.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create an associative array
declare -A excludes

# Build an associative array of directories containing the file
while read line; do
  excludes[$(dirname "$line")]=1
  echo "excluded: $(dirname "$line")" >&2
done <<EOT
$(find . -name "*protein.fasta" -print)
EOT

# Walk through all directories, print only those not in array
find . -type d \
| while read line ; do
  if [[ ! ${excludes[$line]} ]]; then
    echo "$line"
  fi
done
```

For me, this returns:

```
.
./dir3
./dir4
```

All of which are directories that do not contain a file matching `*.protein.fasta`.  Of course, you can replace the last `echo "$line"` with whatever you need to do with these directories.

**Alternately:**

If what you're really looking for is just the list of top-level directories that do not contain the matching file in any subdirectory, the following bash one-liner may be sufficient:

```
for i in *; do test -d "$i" && ( find "$i" -name '*protein.fasta' | grep -q . || echo "$i" ); done
```

Comment: yeah great,this part seems OK ,don't know how to deal with the rest

Comment: I need to run a program with a file which is in directory i and its name is name of the directory plus .DNA.fasta **it is not working in this way that I have used do you have any idea ?**                                                               for i in *; do test -d "$i" && ( find "$i" -name '*protein.fasta' | grep -q . || exec "myprogram" "$i.DNA.fasta" ); done

Comment: If you have new tests that you've run, please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11932067/edit) to include those tests and their results.  Comments like this absolutely suck when it comes to code formatting.  Also, is it `*.DNS.fasta` like in your question, or `*.protein.fasta` like your example?  Please clarify [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11932067/edit).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in *; do

test -d "$dir" && ( find "$dir" -name '*protein.fasta' | grep -q . ||     Programfoo"$dir/$dir.DNA.fasta");
done
```